# Is it possible to solve quadratic programming problem with gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization, gradient-descent

Assume that we have this quadratic function:

$$ J = \frac {1}{2}x^TQx + c^Tx $$

And our gradient is the derivative:

$$ J_g = x^TQ + c^T $$

We want to minimize $J$ and we can do that with setting $J_g = 0$ and solve for $x^T $.

Or we can use gradient descent.

$$x^T_{k+1} = x^T_{k} +\alpha J_g(x_{k})$$

Where $\alpha > 0$ is a small number positive number.

That sounds easy. But how would I do if I want to minimize $J$ with constraints:

$$Ax \leq b $$
$$x \geq 0$$

What would I do then? What method should I use?
Can I use if-statements to check when $x$ is outside of the cobstraints?

Comment: If computing $AA^T$ is not very expensive, one may use the projected gradient descent.

Comment: @zeNanLi what do you mean?

Comment: What you want to solve is a quadratic optimization problem with linear constraints? right? For this problem, the projected gradient descent will work.

Comment: @ZeNanLi Thank you. But how do I apply the constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reformulate the constraints as
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} A \\ -I \end{pmatrix} x \leq \begin{pmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
And denote $\begin{pmatrix} A \\ -I \end{pmatrix}$ by $\bar{A}$, denote $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ by $\bar{b}$. 
Thus the original problem is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
{\min} & {\frac{1}{2} x^TQx + c^T x} \\
{\text{s.t.}} & {\bar{A}x \leq \bar{b}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
To apply the gradient descent to this problem, we need one more step:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \bar{x} = x_k - (Qx_k+c), \\
& x_{k+1} = \operatorname{proj}_{\bar{A}x \leq \bar{b}}(\bar{x}),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\operatorname{proj}_{\bar{A}x \leq \bar{b}}(\cdot)$ is projection operator:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{proj}_{\bar{A}x \leq \bar{b}}(\bar{x}) = \arg\min_{\bar{A}x \leq \bar{b}} \|x - \bar{x}\|^2.
\end{equation}
The projection operator can be solved by [proximal gradient method.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210394/projection-of-a-point-onto-a-convex-polyhedra)

And one can refer to [Quadratic Programming](https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter3.pdf) for some other methods (e.g. SQP).

Comment: Is SQP better to use?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson, in my humble opinion, if the scale of your problem is not very large, the interior point method and SQP is recommended. However, if the scale is very large, maybe you can use the projected gradient descent or semidefinite relaxation method.

Comment: I think I will use the simplest method first, your suggestion. So all I need to do is to first do gradient descent and then corrects it with projection, which is minimize on specific constraints? How should I minimize with constraints? Using simplex method?

Comment: I could not understand your second question exactly. But what you need to do is gradient descent and then corrects it with projection. The simplex method is not suitable for this quadratic programming.

Comment: But how should I minimize the $||x - \bar x||^2 $? I can see that this is typical least square, if I exclude the constraints.

Comment: Can you show an example ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210394/projection-of-a-point-onto-a-convex-polyhedra

Comment: Same answer. Did not help me.